# How to get parent and child table date from Stored Procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using  Stored Procedure in Entity Framework. I get parent value and its child by @id parameter easily but this time i want to get a LIST of parent table object and child of each parent object

like this picture

[image]

```
     var command = myContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetNewsForUser] @id";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", "9f13f132-4536-4111-a73e-61a97a52d226"));

            try
            {
                myContext.Database.Connection.Open();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext;


                UserNews.UserName = objectContext.Translate<string>(reader).FirstOrDefault();

                // to get nex select set from Stored Procedure
                reader.NextResult();

                UserNews.NewsInfos = objectContext.Translate<NewsInfo>(reader).ToList();
            }
            finally
            {
                myContext.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }


CREATE Procedure GetNewsForUser

@id nvarchar(50)
as

BEGIN

select UserName  from  AspNetUsers where id= @id
select NewsId, NewsTitle from News where UserId = @id
End
```

Please help me to modify my C# code and t-sql to achieve  LIST of parent table object and child of each parent object

i want to fill these with data

```
        IList<GetAllNewsForUser> li = null;
        GetAllNewsForUser g = new GetAllNewsForUser();
        g.UserName = "";
        g.NewsInfos = null;
        li.Add(g);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is join query between AspNetUsers table and News table. Then you need to order the set. In your C# code, once you get the set in a list, you can bind it to a grid that is grouped by user name or for simplicity you can loop through the set filling in the presentation object you are using. Look through the following code:

```
SELECT  UserName, NewsId, NewsTitle
FROM    AspNetUsers u JOIN News n 
        ON u.Id = n.UserId
Order by UserName, NewsTitle
```

Loop through the above list changing group everytime the username is different

```
var userNewsList = repository.GetAllUserNews();

foreach(var item in userNewsList)
{
    if(userName != item.UserName)
    {
        //print the userName only once
    }

    //print the NewsTitle and NewsId
}
```

You may need to create a new Entity that matches the result set from the query if you do not have one. Let's say the entity name is UserNews. Then it follows

```
var resultSet = objectContext.Translate<UserNews>(reader);
```

The Translate method returns an ObjectResult, you can then loop through this set (resultSet) using code like in this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738847(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use a Dictionary to load the data the way you want.

usersLi = objectContext.Translate(reader).ToList(); 
var  newsContainer = new Dictionary()

```
foreach (var item in usersLi) 
{
    if( !newsContainer.ContainsKey( item.Username))
    {
        newsContainer.Add(item.UserName, new List<NewsInfo>());     
    }

    var newsInfo = new NewsInfo();

    newsInfo.NewsTitle = item.Title;
    newsInfo.NewsId = item.Id;

    newsContainer[item.UserName].Add(newsInfo);
}
```

The newsContainer.Keys gives you the userNames, newsContainer[username] gives you the list of NewsInfo.

Comment: Thank you for helping but how can i fill my business object from stored procedure ? like this 

    UserNews.UserName = objectContext.Translate<string>(reader).FirstOrDefault();

                // to get nex select set from Stored Procedure
                reader.NextResult();

                UserNews.NewsInfos = objectContext.Translate<NewsInfo>(reader).ToList();


     IList<GetAllNewsForUser> li = null;
        GetAllNewsForUser g = new GetAllNewsForUser();
        g.UserName = "";
        g.NewsInfos = null;
        li.Add(g);

Comment: well i want to assign the the newslist to each user like this :

           usersLi = objectContext.Translate<GetAllNewsForUser>(reader).ToList();
               

                    foreach (var item in usersLi)
                    {
                        GetAllNewsForUser ii = new GetAllNewsForUser();
                        ii.UserName = item.UserName;
                        ii.NewsInfos = item.NewsInfos;
                        FinalList.Add(ii);
                    }

Comment: It's working :) i really appreciated your time and effort, God bless you